# Implemented ArrayList not updating when I call my own Merge sort function

Tags: python-3.x, class, recursion, arraylist, mergesort

I have tried creating my own ArrayList class, and I am trying to implement a sorting function. I have implemented a recursive version of Merge sort as my sorting function, however when I call the function to sort my ArrayList, none of the values are updated.

When I try creating and sorting a random ArrayList like this:

```
    ArrList = ArrayList()

    for i in range(10):
        n = random.random()
        ArrList.append(int(n*100))

    print(ArrList.to_list()) # output:[36, 91, 10, 53, 91, 2, 63, 28, 51, 19]

    ArrList.sort()

    print(ArrList.to_list()) # output:[36, 91, 10, 53, 91, 2, 63, 28, 51, 19]
```

The Merge Sort Function works, but the list does not update. In order for the list to update, I need to add this:

```
    ArrList = ArrayList()

    for i in range(10):
        n = random.random()
        ArrList.append(int(n*100))

    print(ArrList.to_list()) # output: [4, 41, 22, 70, 0, 88, 53, 16, 34, 2]

    ArrList = ArrList.sort()

    print(ArrList.to_list()) # output: [0, 2, 4, 16, 22, 34, 41, 53, 70, 88]
```

How do I make it so that the top code works and gets the list to update?

Here is my Sort Function code:

Merge Functions:

```
    def __mergeDesc(self, left, right):
        result = ArrayList()
        l = 0
        r = 0
  
        while(l < left.length() and r < right.length()):

            if left.get(l) > right.get(r):
                result.append(left.get(l))
                l += 1
            else:
                result.append(right.get(r))
                r += 1

        while(l < left.length()):
            result.append(left.get(l))
            l+=1

        while(r < right.length()):
            result.append(right.get(r))
            r+=1

        return self
  
    def __mergeAsc(self, left, right):
        result = ArrayList()
        l = 0
        r = 0
  
        while(l < left.length() and r < right.length()):

            if left.get(l) < right.get(r):
                result.append(left.get(l))
                l += 1
            else:
                result.append(right.get(r))
                r += 1

        while(l < left.length()):
            result.append(left.get(l))
            l+=1

        while(r < right.length()):
            result.append(right.get(r))
            r+=1

        return self
```

Divide Function:

```
    def __merge_sort(self, AList, descending=False):

        self = AList

        if self.length() == 0:
            return self

        mid = self.length()//2

        if self.length() == 1:
            return self
  
        left = ArrayList()
        right = ArrayList()

        for i in range(mid):
            left.append(self.get(i))

        for i in range(mid, self.length()):
            right.append(self.get(i))

        left = self.__merge_sort(left, descending)
        right = self.__merge_sort(right, descending)

        if descending:
            return self.__mergeDesc(left, right)
        else:
            return self.__mergeAsc(left, right)
```

This is where I call the Merge sort functions

```
    def sort(self, descending=False):

        self = self.__merge_sort(self, descending)
        return self
```